# Draw Line & Delete Selected Rectangle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I want to draw a line which is going to be resized based on rectangle width and want to delete selected rectangle on button click event.Line to be drawn between rectangle as image shown below
[image: Samplr]

Below is the fiddle you can check

[Test][2]

```js
d3.select('#rectangle').on('click', function(){ new Rectangle(); });
var w = 600, h = 500;
var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr({width: w, height: h});

function Rectangle() {
    var self = this, rect, rectData = [], isDown = false, m1, m2, isDrag = false;
    
    svg.on('mousedown', function() {
        m1 = d3.mouse(this);
        if (!isDown && !isDrag) {
            self.rectData = [ { x: m1[0], y: m1[1] }, { x: m1[0], y: m1[1] } ];
            self.rectangleElement = d3.select('svg').append('rect').attr('class', 'rectangle').call(dragR);
            self.pointElement1 = d3.select('svg').append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC1);
            self.pointElement2 = d3.select('svg').append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC2);            
            self.pointElement3 = svg.append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC3);
            self.pointElement4 = svg.append('circle').attr('class', 'pointC').call(dragC4);
            updateRect();
            isDrag = false;
        } else { 
            isDrag = true;
        }
        isDown = !isDown;     
    })
    
    .on('mousemove', function() {
        m2 = d3.mouse(this);
        if(isDown && !isDrag) { 
            self.rectData[1] = { x: m2[0], y: m2[1] };
            updateRect();
        } 
    });  
    
    function updateRect() {  
        rect = d3.select(self.rectangleElement[0][0]);
        rect.attr({
            x: self.rectData[1].x - self.rectData[0].x > 0 ? self.rectData[0].x :  self.rectData[1].x,
            y: self.rectData[1].y - self.rectData[0].y > 0 ? self.rectData[0].y :  self.rectData[1].y,
            width: Math.abs(self.rectData[1].x - self.rectData[0].x),
            height: Math.abs(self.rectData[1].y - self.rectData[0].y)
        });   
        
        var point1 = d3.select(self.pointElement1[0][0]).data(self.rectData);
        point1.attr('r', 5)
              .attr('cx', self.rectData[0].x)
              .attr('cy', self.rectData[0].y);        
        var point2 = d3.select(self.pointElement2[0][0]).data(self.rectData);
        point2.attr('r', 5)
              .attr('cx', self.rectData[1].x)
              .attr('cy', self.rectData[1].y);
        var point3 = d3.select(self.pointElement3[0][0]).data(self.rectData);
        point3.attr('r', 5)
              .attr('cx', self.rectData[1].x)
              .attr('cy', self.rectData[0].y);        
        var point3 = d3.select(self.pointElement4[0][0]).data(self.rectData);
        point3.attr('r', 5)
              .attr('cx', self.rectData[0].x)
              .attr('cy', self.rectData[1].y);
    }
    
    var dragR = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', dragRect);
    
    function dragRect() {
        var e = d3.event;
        for(var i = 0; i < self.rectData.length; i++){
            d3.select(self.rectangleElement[0][0])
                .attr('x', self.rectData[i].x += e.dx )
                .attr('y', self.rectData[i].y += e.dy );
        }
        rect.style('cursor', 'move');
        updateRect();
    }
    
    var dragC1 = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', dragPoint1);
    var dragC2 = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', dragPoint2);
    var dragC3 = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', dragPoint3);
    var dragC4 = d3.behavior.drag().on('drag', dragPoint4);
    
    function dragPoint1() {
        var e = d3.event;
        d3.select(self.pointElement1[0][0])
            .attr('cx', function(d) { return d.x += e.dx })
            .attr('cy', function(d) { return d.y += e.dy });        
        updateRect();   
    }   
    
    function dragPoint2() {
        var e = d3.event;
        d3.select(self.pointElement2[0][0])
            .attr('cx', self.rectData[1].x += e.dx )
            .attr('cy', self.rectData[1].y += e.dy );
        updateRect();   
    }   
    
    function dragPoint3() {
        var e = d3.event;
        d3.select(self.pointElement3[0][0])
            .attr('cx', self.rectData[1].x += e.dx )
            .attr('cy', self.rectData[0].y += e.dy );     
        updateRect();   
    }   
    
    function dragPoint4() {
        var e = d3.event;
        d3.select(self.pointElement4[0][0])
            .attr('cx', self.rectData[0].x += e.dx )
            .attr('cy', self.rectData[1].y += e.dy );
        updateRect();   
    }   
    
}//end Rectangle
```

```css
svg {
    border: solid 1px red;
}
rect {
    fill: lightblue;
    stroke: blue;
    stroke-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<button id='rectangle'>Rectangle</button>
```